# pandas datetime index unique difference

Tags: python, pandas

The following works for getting unique difference in consecutive datetime index.

```py
# Data
import pandas
d = pandas.DataFrame({"a": [x for x in range(5)]})
d.index = pandas.date_range("2021-01-01 00:00:00", "2021-01-01 01:00:00", freq="15min")

# Get difference
delta = d.index.to_series().diff().astype("timedelta64[m]").unique()
delta
# array([nan, 15.])
```

But I am not clear where the `nan` comes from. I am only interested in the `15` minutes. Is `delta[1]` a reliable way to get it or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first row doesn't have anything to `diff` against, so its NaT.

```
>>> d.index.to_series().diff()
2021-01-01 00:00:00        NaT
2021-01-01 00:15:00   00:15:00
2021-01-01 00:30:00   00:15:00
2021-01-01 00:45:00   00:15:00
2021-01-01 01:00:00   00:15:00
Freq: 15T, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

From [pandas.Series.unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html#pandas-series-unique): *Uniques are returned in order of appearance.*. Since that `NaT` is guaranteed to be the first element in the returned list it is okay to do `delta[1]` as you suggest. Assuming you have at least 2 rows and you don't have `NaT` in the data.

More generally, if you don't want that first value in a diff, you can slice it off

```
>>> d.index.to_series().diff()[1:]
2021-01-01 00:15:00   00:15:00
2021-01-01 00:30:00   00:15:00
2021-01-01 00:45:00   00:15:00
2021-01-01 01:00:00   00:15:00
Freq: 15T, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `diff` , the first item will return NaN in pandas which is not same as R ~

```
d.index.to_series().diff()
Out[713]: 
2021-01-01 00:00:00               NaT
2021-01-01 00:15:00   0 days 00:15:00
2021-01-01 00:30:00   0 days 00:15:00
2021-01-01 00:45:00   0 days 00:15:00
2021-01-01 01:00:00   0 days 00:15:00
Freq: 15T, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```